# Additional login to OAuth2 service in Hosted Blazor WASM

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, blazor

I'd like to add a DigiKey lookup to my Hosted Blazor WASM app (.Net 7).
The DigiKey api is [OAuth2](https://developer.digikey.com/documentation/oauth) and requires a  separate sign in. For my app, all users are required to login using AzureAD, and occasionally some of them will want to access this DigiKey api.  So I only want to require the sign in on an as-needed basis.  I'd like to use [Microsoft's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0#make-api-calls-from-the-client-to-the-server-api-in-order-to-call-third-party-apis) guidance, but there just is not enough detail for me to follow.

On the server side, I've added both authentication services:

```
var digikeyOptions = Configuration.GetSection(DigiKeyOptions.DigiKey).Get<DigiKeyOptions>() ?? throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(nameof(DigiKeyOptions));
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddCookie("DigikeyCookie")
   .AddOAuth(nameof(AuthenticationSchemes.DigiKey), options =>
   {                
      options.ClientId = digikeyOptions.ClientId;
      options.ClientSecret = digikeyOptions.ClientSecret;
      options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/digikey-oauth/login-callback");
      options.AuthorizationEndpoint = digikeyOptions.AuthEndpoint;
      options.TokenEndpoint = digikeyOptions.TokenEndpoint;
      options.SaveTokens = true;
      options.SignInScheme = "DigikeyCookie";
      options.ClaimsIssuer = DigiKeyOptions.DigiKey;
      options.ClaimActions.MapAll();
   })            
   .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

I have a server side controller I've tested with:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DigiKeyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("Login/{returnUrl}")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string? returnUrl)
    {
        var redirectUrl = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) ? returnUrl : "/";
        return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl }, nameof(AuthenticationSchemes.DigiKey));
    }

    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = nameof(AuthenticationSchemes.DigiKey))]
    [HttpGet("ProductDetails/{partNumber}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ProductDetails?>> GetProductDetailsAsync(string partNumber)
    {
        if (!User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false) return Unauthorized();
        await Task.Yield();
        return Ok(null);
    }
}
```

This seems to work, on the client I can call  `Navigation.NavigateTo($"api/digikey/login/returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(Navigation.Uri)}", true );` and with fiddler I see it successfully getting the access and refresh tokens.

I however haven't found any guidance on setting up the client side.
For the AAD login I've followed MS guidance, and am using the Graph API to determine the user's groups:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("ServerAPI"));
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore(options =>
{
   foreach (var group in AuthorizationGroups.AdGroups)
   {
      options.AddPolicy(Enum.GetName(group.Name)!, policy => policy.RequireClaim("directoryGroup", group.Guid.ToString()));
   }
});
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount>(options =>
{
   options.ProviderOptions.Cache.CacheLocation = "localStorage";
   builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
   options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Scope"] ?? string.Empty);
   //options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
}).AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount, CustomAccountFactory>();

builder.Services.AddGraphClient();
```

I've read msal can handle oauth2 so I think I wouldn't need to do much more than adding

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
   builder.Configuration.Bind("DigiKey", options.ProviderOptions);
   options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "code";           
});
```

(although I'm not sure what I'm using for the ProviderOptions properties).
What direction do I head to next?  It seems since  will always say the user is authenticated (to AzureAD), so do I try to add a claim to the current user? Not sure how to do any of this, I can't find documentation for it.